# Catch a double click in vscode extension

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

As the title says - how can I catch a double click vs single click in the TreeView? I tried using the setTimeout way but I find it quite lacking and buggy. Is there a better way to do it than setting a timer?